# Writing to SQL Server Compact database from jquery mouseup event

Tags: c#, jquery, webforms, sql-server-ce, mouseup

I'm working on an asp.net c# empty web forms project. I have a SQL Server Compact database with a single table that I want to use to store information about an elements (x,y) coordinates.

The database should be updated with the new coordinates for a particular panel when the `mouseup` event is triggered on that panel (a div essentially). The solution doesn't need to be ajax, submitting the page will be ok.

The problem is that there is no `mouseup` type of event for an `<asp:Panel>` element and on the other side I'm not sure how I would trigger something server-side from jQuery. Getting the coordinates using jQuery is easy enough, but what would I do from there?

Are hidden inputs ok for this? Give me your best solution - I don't need to see code, just give me a better idea of what i should be doing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check what exactly `asp:Panel` is getting rendered in browser by firebug, suppose it renders as `div` then you can use jquery's `.mouseup()` function and bind this event to what ever element that panel is rendered. Suppose if that asp:panel is rendered as div then look this below code for sample.

```
 <div id="asp_panel">
  Click here
</div>
$('#asp_panel').mouseup(function() {

    $.ajax({
            url: "HelloWorld.asmx/Hello",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: "{}", // if your method takes any parameter pass it in here in json format.
            dataType: "JSON"
            success: function(msg) {
                alert(msg);
            }
    });
});
```

Comment: but can i do something like use jquery to call a service server-side (in place of where you have an alert)? Or am i stuck hiding the x and y values inside hidden inputs?

Comment: In my question I'm trying to ask how to do that. Maybe I wasn't very clear.  I do already know how to attach to the mouseup event, it's what happens after that which I don't understand.

Comment: i have edited my answer, you can see i have called up a service `Hello`